# SQS → Lambda Problem With maximumBatchingWindow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Our intention is to trigger a lambda when messages are received in an SQS queue.

- we only want one invocation of the lambda to run at a time (maximum concurrency of one)
- We would like for the lambda to be triggered every time one of the following is true:

  - There are 10,000 messages in the queue
  - Five minutes has passed since the last invocation of the lambda

Our consumer lambda is dealing with an API with limited API calls and strict concurrency limits. The above solution ensures we never encounter concurrency issues and we can batch our calls together, ensuring we never consume too many API calls.

Here is our `serverless.yml` configuration

```json
functions:
  sqs-consumer:
    name: sqs-consumer
    handler: handlers.consume_handler
    reservedConcurrency: 1 // maximum concurrency of 1
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: !GetAtt
            - SqsQueue
            - Arn
          batchSize: 10000
          maximumBatchingWindow: 300
    timeout: 900

resources:
  Resources:
    SqsQueue:
      Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
      Properties:
        QueueName: sqs-queue
        VisibilityTimeout: 5400  # 6x greater than the lambda timeout
```

The above does not give us the desired behavior. We are seeing our lambda triggered every 1 to 3 minutes (instead of 5). It indeed is using batches because we’ll see multiple messages being processed in a single invocation, but with even just one or two messages in the queue at a time it doesn’t wait 5 minutes to trigger the lambda.

Our messages are extremely small, so it's not possible we're coming anywhere close to the 6mb limit.

We would expect the only time the lambda is triggered to be when either 10,000 messages have accumulated in the queue or five minutes have transpired since the previous invocation. Instead we are seeing the lambda invoked anywhere in between every 1 to 3 minutes with a batch size that never even breaks 100, much less 10,000.

The largest batch size I’ve seen it invoke the lambda with so far has been 28, and sometimes with only one message in the queue it’ll invoke the function when it’s only been one minute since the previous invocation.

We would like to avoid using Kinesis, as the volume we’re dealing with truly doesn’t warrant it.

Comment: I'm reading the SQS doc; It mentions that the total size of the events should not exceed the invocation payload quota of 6MB. Otherwise, batchSize and maximumBatchingWindow might not be honored. This is not the case for you?

Comment: Definitely not. Our messages are ~2kB each

Comment: I am observing pretty much exactly the same thing. Have opened a support case. Will report back if there is a solution to what seems like a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reply from AWS Support:

> As per the Case ID 10802672001, I understand that you have an SQS
> event source mapping on Lambda with a batch size of 500 and batch
> Window of 60 seconds. I further understand that you have observed the
> lambda function invocation has fewer messages than 500 in a batch and
> is not waiting for batch window time configured while receiving the
> messages. You would like to know why lambda is being invoked prior to
> meeting any of the above configured conditions and seek our assistance
> in troubleshooting the same. Please correct me if I misunderstood your
> query by any means.
>
> Initially, I would like to thank you for sharing the detailed
> correspondence along with the screenshot of the logs, it was indeed
> very helpful in troubleshooting the issue.
>
> Firstly, I used the internal tools to check the configuration of your
> lambda function "sd_dch_archivebatterydata" and observed that there
> is no throttling in the lambda function and there is no reserved
> concurrency configured. As you might already be aware that Lambda is
> meant to scale while polling from SQS queues and thus it is
> recommended not to use reserving concurrency, as it is going against
> the design of the event source. On checking log screenshot shared by
> you, I observed there were no errors.
>
> Regarding your query, please allow me to answer them as follows:
>
> - Please understand here that Batch size is the maximum number of messages that lambda will read from the queue in one batch for a
>   single invocation. It should be considered as the maximum number of
>   messages (up to) that can be received in a single batch but not as a
>   fixed value that can be received at all times in a single invocation.
>   -- Please see "When Lambda invokes the target function, the event can contain multiple items, up to a configurable maximum batch size" in
>   the official documentation here [1] for more information on the same.
> - I would also like to add that, according to the internal architecture of how the SQS service is designed, Lambda pollers will
>   poll the messages from the queue using the "ReceiveMessage" API
>   calls and invokes the Lambda function.
>   -- Please refer the documentation [2] which states the following "If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than 1,000), you
>   most likely get fewer messages than you requested per ReceiveMessage
>   call. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you
>   might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage
>   response. If this happens, repeat the request".
>   -- Thus, we can see that the number of messages that can be obtained in a single lambda invocation with a certain batch size depends on the
>   number of messages in an SQS queue and the SQS service internal
>   implementation.
> - Also, batch window is the maximum amount of time that the poller waits to gather the messages from the queue before invoking the
>   function. However, this applies when there are no messages in the
>   queue. Thus, as soon as there is a message in the queue, the Lambda
>   function will be invoked without any further due without waiting for
>   the batch window time specified. You can refer to the
>   "WaitTimeSeconds" parameter in the "ReceiveMessage" API.
>   -- The batch window just ensures that lambda starts polling after certain time so that enough messages are present in the queue.
>   However, there are other factors like size of messages, incoming
>   volume, etc that can affect this behavior.
> - Additionally, I would like to confirm that Polls from SQS in Lambda is of Synchronous invocation type and it has an invocation payload
>   limit size of 6MB. Please refer the following AWS Documentation for
>   more information on the same [3].
>
> Having said that, I can confirm that this Lambda polling behaviour is
> by design and not a bug. Please be rest assured that there are no
> issues with the lambda and SQS service.

---

Our scenario is to archive to S3, and we want fewer larger files. Looks like our options are potentially kinesis, or running a custom receive application on something like ECS...